# Boto3 EC2.Client DescribeFleets class error 'EC2' object has no attribute 'describe_fleets'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying this code from [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_fleets) but getting the error:

AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'describe_fleets'

```
import boto3
# low level ec2 client
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_fleets(
    DryRun=True,
    MaxResults=100,
    FleetIds=[
        'xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 fleets are reasonably new. You might need to upgrade your boto3:

```
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

I just did that and my version is showing: `boto3-1.7.24`